# Amazon SES Bounce Processing

Tags: civimail, bounce

I have setup Amazon SES to send email from CiviMail. All the stats except bounces are coming back into the system. For bounces I followed this helpful post here https://www.compucorp.co.uk/node/1740 but could not get it to work. Has anyone setup bounce processing with SES and what would the credentials be here. I am using a google apps email so I tried to enter the google account information but that did not work.

- Name: Bounce Handling
- Server: The IMAP server address of your email provider
- Username: Bounce processing email address. e.g. bounce@example.com
- Password: Password of the bounce processing email account
- Localpart: Local-part of the bounce processing email address with a plus symbol. e.g. bounce+
- Return-Path: Leave blank
- Protocol: IMAP
- Source: Leave blank if the email address is only used for bounce handling. If this email is also used for other purposes and have a filter for bounce notifications, fill in the label (folder) used for keep all bounce notifications. e.g. INBOX/CiviMail/Bounce
- Use SSL: Normally Yes unless the email server does not require SSL.
- Used For?: Bounce Processing

Comment: Did you turn off 2 way authentication?

Comment: Hi @PradeepNayak. Yes TFA is turned off for the email address. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does the creds work on normal CiviCRM install?

Comment: Yes. I can send emails from SES and also get the open and link clicks. Can't get the bouncebacks